# Is there any C library for HBase?

Tags: hbase

I need HBase to store large amount of indexing keywords and values (currently using Redis), but I can't find any C library to connect, write or read HBase.

I Googled, but found nothing. Does anybody have an idea? Or is there any similar Hadoop-related database that has mature C library?

Comment: If you can use C++ there is the thrift library which HBase has a file for to generate C++ code to communicate with HBase. I use it with C#. http://thrift.apache.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to consider:

- [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi)
- [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) is another new option to look into.
- You could use a plain REST api calls using [Stargate](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate).

There is a discussion on the HBase bug tracker [HBase-1015](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-1015) about c and c++ clients.

Look into the above options to see what best fits your requirements.

HDFS, upon which hbase is built, is a similar Hadoop-related database that has a C library.

libhdfs is a c based library to access hdfs. It was created using jni.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/LibHDFS

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/libhdfs.html

Here is an example project:

https://github.com/kzk/libhdfs-example

Comment: This has nothing to do with HBase... You proposed a client to HDFS. I don't understand why this response was accepted over the other valid ones.

Comment: The libhdfs portion of the answer is responding to the "Or is there any similar Hadoop-related database that has mature C library?" portion of the question, I will clarify that part of the answer.

Comment: As Nija commented, Thrift is currently the best way for non-jvm clients to connect to hbase, this answers the first part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a pure C HBase client, but there seems to be a C++ client:

https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-native-client

Comment: The link is broken. Can u please update the link?

Comment: The link has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the C++ Hbase client developed by Chip Turner actually goes through Thrift (at least the current code does). So you have a C++ API translated to the Thrift API, translated to the Java API. The one advantage appears to be that the C++ API is trying to hew closely to the original Java API.

Answer (score 1):

A native API for HBase, libhbase, similar to libhdfs is available [here](https://github.com/mapr/libhbase).

You can also download the pre-built packages for CentOS/RedHat and Ubuntu from for HBase 0.98.x from [here](http://package.mapr.com/releases/ecosystem-4.x/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll update the answer with more detail shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi) as a gateway to connect with HBase.